# How do I add a namespace inside nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, namespaces, nopcommerce

I'm using [nopcommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/).

I want to get Stock qty from external data base.

So I add a another project inside Presentation folder and I set the database connection string inside the web config file.

The I try to use new project function inside the Nop.Admin project.

For that I write

```
using ExternalDB;
```

But there is error-

```
The type or namespace name 'ExternalDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Do you have any idea on why it can't find the namespace? How do I add a external project with a external DB inside the nopcommerce?

Comment: which version of nop commerce you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

There's no concept of one project inside another project. You can have a project inside a *solution* in Visual Studio, but that's not the same thing.

You should look at which namespace the `ExternalDB` type is in, and just have a using directive for that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Is "ExternalDB" a project name or a type? 
I guess you miss to add a reference associated with "ExternalDB" to your Admin project.